# AMP-Email: error displaying your dynamic email (INTERNAL_ERROR)

Tags: gmail-api, amp-html, amp-email

I'm trying to send my first AMP email using gmail API from my gmail account to myself (To === From).
I send exactly the same message as provided in the AMP documentation here: https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/email-spec/amp-email-structure/ , including all Content-Type headers for multipart/alternative message. 
But when I receive this message using my chrome gmail client I see only fallback HTML version and banner with error: "Why isn't the dynamic content rendered? There was an error displaying your dynamic email (INTERNAL_ERROR). More info".[image: INTERNAL_ERROR message]

Additional info:

- SPF, DKIM and DMARC are configured correctly, the status is PASS if I
  send email to somebody from my domain. My email service provider is google.
- Developer settings in gmail client is turned on: "Always allow dynamic emails from
  this sender: " .
- If I download this message from inbox as .eml and import it to AMP
  playground here: https://playground.amp.dev/?runtime=amp4email it imported successfully without validation errors. My email opens exactly as it should - as AMP hello world message. [image: My .eml imported to AMP playground]
- I use gmail API to send message and js-base64 to encode it:

  const gmail = google.gmail({ version: 'v1', auth: oauth2Client });

  ```
    const base64EncodedEmail = Base64.encodeURI(email);

    const status = gmail.users.messages
      .send({
        userId: mail_config.ADDRESS,
        uploadType: 'multipart',
        resource: {
          raw: base64EncodedEmail
        }
      })
  ```

The message itself (email variable from the code above) provided in the following code. exampleBody looks ugly, I've tried to use mimemessage npm package to generate it as well with the same INTERNAL_ERROR. Here is just example from AMP email documentation "as is": https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/email-spec/amp-email-structure/

```
  const exampleBody = `Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="001a114634ac3555ae05525685ae"

      --001a114634ac3555ae05525685ae
      Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"; format=flowed; delsp=yes

      Hello World in plain text!

      --001a114634ac3555ae05525685ae
      Content-Type: text/x-amp-html; charset="UTF-8"

      <!doctype html>
      <html ⚡4email>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style amp4email-boilerplate>body{visibility:hidden}</style>
        <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
      Hello World in AMP!
      </body>
      </html>
      --001a114634ac3555ae05525685ae
      Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"

      <span>Hello World in HTML!</span>
      --001a114634ac3555ae05525685ae--`;

      const email =
        'From: ' +
        my_address +
        '\r\nTo: ' +
        my_address +
        '\r\nSubject: ' +
        subject +
        '\r\n' +
        exampleBody;
```

What am I missing here? Please help.

Comment: Can you try sending to another @gmail.com address this way? I suspect this issue is happening because you're sending the email to yourself.

Comment: @fstanis yeah, I've tried this. Another person also see HTML version only, but without error banner. Only clean HTML. When another person opens email source, the AMP content is stripped out - no AMP content or headers in message body at all.
Developer settings in gmail client are turned on to allow dynamic emails from my address for another person as well.

Comment: In that case, I suspect the Gmail API simply doesn't support having a custom (in this case `text/x-amp-html`) mime type.

Comment: @TyutlaevaEkaterina I haven't tried sending using the gmail API, but I have no problem sending amp-emails using services like sendgrid and sparkpost. Maybe to avoid wasting time, try them?

Comment: @alexandr-kazakov Thank you so much! Sendgrid really works for me, I finally send my first AMP email and able to see it. Your comment is the most helpful!

Answer (score -1):

If you are not yet [registered with Google](https://developers.google.com/gmail/ampemail/register) to send dynamic emails, you will not be able to.

For testing out AMP on Gmail you can use the [Gmail AMP for Email playground](https://amp.gmail.dev/playground/) which sends the dynamic email to your gmail inbox.

---

**References:**

- [AMP for Gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/ampemail)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But according to this guide:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/ampemail/testing-dynamic-email
I need to verify test delivering your email from my production system.
"This [whitelisting an email address that can send you dynamic emails for testing purposes] lets you test your dynamic emails on your own accounts before registering to ensure they are working as expected."

Comment: Yes this is correct, if you want to test how your dynamic emails are received when being sent from a production environment, you need to whitelist in your receiving account the production email sender. Did you do this step?

Comment: yes,  I whitelisted my address in gmail client developer settings to allow dynamic emails.

Comment: I also receive the INTERNAL_ERROR message. It appears to be an issue with the Gmail API. There is this open issue in Google's Public Issue Tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/157163977 . Add a start next to the issue number for more visibility

Comment: Thank you so much for reproducing it! It is my issue, but I've added the star.

Comment: I think @Aerials answer is wrong. If there is no registration in Google, and the email address is not added manually, then the AMP-email will not appear, the normal html version of the message is displayed. The screenshot shows an error of the following type: INTERNAL ERROR
I think the problem is in the way the email is sent and it has nothing to do with what Aerials writes